# C++11 range based auto for loop by value, reference, and pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, auto

I know how to use auto keyword in for loop to iterate this array either by value or reference.

```
struct A {
 void fun() {};
};

int main() {
  A a[2];

  // Value
  for (auto x : a) {
    x.fun();
  }

  // Ref
  for (auto& x : a) {
    x.fun();
  }

  // Pointer
  //for (...) {
    x->fun();
  }
}
```

So I am looking third version of this convention. How do I use pointer here?

Comment: A pointer is a value type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
A a[2];
for(auto& x_:a){
  auto* x = &x_;
  // code
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't. If you want a pointer, either write a classical for-loop, or loop by reference and take the address.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not recommending it, but if you insist on using pointer `->` syntax, just make an array of `A*` and treat it like a value (i.e. do regular `auto` in the range-for loop)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
 void fun() { std::cout << "fun \n"; };
};

int main() {
  A* a[2];

  // Pointer
  for (auto x : a) {
    x->fun();
  }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1886bcafaf262a4)

Comment: Ew, no, don't... and Xeo never said to do this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree on the ew, but just wanted to point it out in case the OP insists on using `->` syntax. Updated the answer, tnx.