# Access pointer in range based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I have a dynamic array wrapper template like this:

```
class Wrapper {
  public:
    T* const start;
    T* const end;
    T* begin() const { return start; }
    T* end() const { return end; }
    /*
       more code
    */
};
```

which gives value and reference access via the loops:

```
Wrapper<T> wrapper;
for(auto val : wrapper) {
  //do smth to value
}
for(auto& ref : wrapper) {
  //do smth to reference
}
```

. I now want to create a range based for loop which is equivalent to this:

```
for(auto ptr = wrapper.start; ptr != wrapper.end; ptr++) {
  //do smth to pointer
}
```

, i.e. I want a range based loop over wrapper to give access to a pointer. Is there a way to do this without creating an array of pointers to pointers inside my wrapper?

**Edit**:

Dani's solution in the comment works as has already been pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239507/c11-range-based-auto-for-loop-by-value-reference-and-pointer?rq=1). I was actually wondering if there was a way to make the following syntax:

```
for(auto ptr : wrapper) {
  //do smth
}
```

work as the C-style for loop above.

Comment: You can take a pointer from the reference

Comment: You mean something like: `for(auto& ref : wrapper) { auto ptr = &ref; }` ? Can I somehow alter the `begin()` and `end()` methods to get this working implicitly insite this: `for(auto ptr : wrapper) { /* do smth */ }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own custom iterator that returns a `T*` when dereferenced

```
class iterator {
    T* ptr;
public:
    explicit iterator(T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    iterator& operator++() {ptr++; return *this;}
    bool operator!=(iterator other) const {return ptr != other.ptr;}
    T* operator*() const {return ptr;}
};
```

And then return this iterator from your `begin` and `end` functions.

I think it is slightly surprising behavior for an array wrapper to have though.

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/juoqZuUxS5fP8pK1).

Comment: That looks great. Thanks. The array wrapper is just a minimal example.